# Rails Routing with Enum User Roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-routing

I created a users table and implemented Devise. I then added an enum role to the user table so that I can identify admins, guides, and members.

What I'd like to do is limit routes for certain resources based on the enum user type. I've tried:

```
resources :users.guide do
    get 'guide/dashboard', :to => 'guides#dashboard'
end
```

and some variants, but with no success. The above gives me the error:

```
undefined method `guide' for :users:Symbol
```

I've done some poking around and can't seem to find a good response. I'm avoiding CanCanCan and Rolify as I'd like to keep things as basic as possible. Any ideas? Thanks!

**Edited Per Below Suggestion**

So I went and updated my routes as suggested below so that the file looks similar to this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  #open to public
  root 'welcome#index'
  resources :guides, only: [:show], param: :username
  resources :itineraries, only: [:index] #, only: [:index, :show] 

  authenticate :user, ->(u) { u.guide? } do
    resources :guides, only: [:edit, :destroy], param: :username
    get 'guide/dashboard', :to => 'guides#dashboard'
  end

  resources :locations, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy, :index, :show]

end
```

For whatever reason, the guide profile show/edit works fine; the dashboard works fine; but the other things outside of the authenticate block (itineraries and locations resources) don't work, I get redirected to the Devise login page. They are outside (and in one case above) the authenticate block, not sure why this is occurring with some resources/routes and not others.

Comment: That restriction sounds like it should be done on the controller, not on the route (the route has no idea if there's a user logged in or not or it's role). If you want to limit that, add a before_action and send the user away if it doesn't have the right role.

Answer (score 1):

You can use devise helpers. With `authenticate`, it is possible to make resources and routes that will ask for authentication before they can be accessed. Replacing `authenticate` with `authenticated` causes the resource to simply be unavailable if the user is not authenticated. Both helpers take an optional scope and block to provide constraints on the model instance itself.

```
authenticate :user, ->(u) { u.guide? } do
  get 'guide/dashboard', :to => 'guides#dashboard'
end
```

Comment: So this partially helped, but please see edited issue above, any other suggestions with what I've provided? Thank you!

Comment: @MikeN. do you have `before_action :authenticate_user` in itineraries and locations controllers?

Comment: no, I just double checked, I had a before action: check_admin method call but I commented that out and it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is `limit routes for certain resources based on the enum user type`. I suggest you should implement the authorization stuff instead of trying to create more resources/scopes in your route, it's correctness.